# What to do if question hasn't received much attention despite the bounty?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659869/setting-five-alarms-daily-and-update-them-on-a-button-click) question on SO quite a while ago.

I didn't receive much attention (I don't see why). Realizing this I put a bounty on it, still no one has answered the question yet. This question perfectly complies with the Q/A pattern of SO and it IS a real question.

What should I do to get it answered?

Comment: You started your bounty 7 hours ago. Give it some time.

Answer (score 7):

Placing a bounty on a question doesn't guarantee that you'll get an answer.  What it **does** guarantee is that it'll be in the [featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured), *that* is where it'll draw attention.

> I didn't receive much attention...

Attention can be gauged in many ways, for you, the attention you are looking for is in the form of an answer; however, attention could be given in the form of views, comments, edits, votes, etc...

[As was mentioned by Bart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142322/what-to-do-if-question-hasnt-received-much-attention-despite-the-bounty#comment403304_142322), you placed a bounty on your post only a few hours ago (`2012-08-05 08:04 UTC`) - you'll need to be a little more patient. Consider time zone differences.

Notice also in the comments you were asked to add some more information and context to the post.  You have since [made some edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11659869/revisions) but saying `"...it didnt work..."`is not really adding more info.  If it worked you wouldn't be posting a question about it :)

Try to be as specific as possible and provide as much **relevant** context as you can.  This will help the community greatly in providing you with the assistance you are looking for.

---

Please do not re-post the question in an attempt to get more attention.  The question will be closed and if you do this enough times you might even get a temporary suspension.

---

Related reading materials -

- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

**What *exactly* is the code supposed to do?**

You do mention a button triggers the alarms, but you don't tell us exactly *how* the alarms are triggered using the button press or show the code for the button. While it's clearly a loop, it helps to give people this information before they start looking at the code for the problems. In other words, time spent trying to figure out what the code is supposed to do is time spent not looking for problems.

Also, whose to say the problem isn't the button itself. You should show that code too, if nothing else but to dispel doubts that this is the problem.

**What doesn't work?**

You also don't say what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Does it not compile? Does it fire the alarms in the wrong order? Do the alarms never fire? Tell us exactly what doesn't work.

**Error Messages**

Additionally, what error messages did you get, if any? I know you're new, but you should recognize that error messages are very valuable, as they tell you exactly what is wrong with a specific section of your code. You might not be able to understand them yourself yet -- this comes with experience -- but recognize that people who want to help you will need this information.

**What did you try so far?**

Lastly, what have you tried? This is important because it gives people who want to help you a starting point. In other words, you won't get answers that tell you things you've already done. This is a huge waste of time for both you and the people trying to help you if every answer posted is followed by a comment by you saying "no ! i tried that alredy!"

**Thus, include the following information in each post:**

- Say what the code is supposed to do. Don't make users reverse engineer your code and try to figure out what it's supposed to do.
- Say what the code isn't doing and how it's failing. Be clear about this part.
- List what you've tried yourself.
- Show error messages and the line that the error points to.

**Edit before posting bounties**

Honestly, I'm really not sure you needed to post a bounty on this, at least not yet. Sure, a bounty will get your question attention, but so will making sure your question is clear and easy for the volunteers on Stack Overflow to quickly understand.

Remember, every time you edit your question with new, relevant information, it gets bumped back to the top of the page so that others will see it. Thus, look at comments people leave, and if they ask for more information from you, edit your question to add that in.

If you still don't get answers after making sure your question meets the above criteria, then it's time to bring out the big guns and post a bounty. Good luck!

Comment: Is this too long to add to the auto comment script? ;)

Comment: Not if we require every new user to install a user script that parses the link to this question and displays all the answers in a larger, custom formatted no-limit comment :)